# Official Page for Lotus Notes API Java Library Download

Tags: lotus-notes

I am writing a java program to integrate with IBM Notes Client. 
IBM provided Notes Client Java UI APIs, notes.jar for the integration. I can find it in local machine if I have installed the domino or notes client.

The path could be

- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Domino\jvm\lib\ext\Notes.jar
- C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\jvm\lib\ext\Notes.jar

Is there any official page for Notes Client Java UI APIs, notes.jar download?

Reference: http://www-10.lotus.com/ldd/ddwiki.nsf/dx/Notes_Client_Java_UI_APIs-v8.5.2

Comment: I am pretty sure that the answer is no. You need a product installation in order to get the notes.jar.

Comment: I don't think the Java UI API is in notes.jar. That file is the back-end API. I don't know what jar file the UI API is in, but I also agree it's not separately downloadable. It is included with the recent versions of the notes client install.

Comment: Refer to reference, the api is really in that file. With that jar, it can execute nearly all methods provided in notes api.

Comment: Hmmm.. I don't see the UI classes in the notes.jar on my machine, which is Notes 9.0.1. They would be under com.ibm.notes, and the only thing under com.ibm in that jar file is com.ibm.sslight. But if everything you really need is in that file, then Per's answer is definitely correct. You need a licensed installation of Notes or Domino to use those classes. They depend on nlsxbe.dll, nnotes.dll, and various other dll files that are part of the client or server installation and cannot legally be copied to other systems. (And IBM has lots of lawyers, so it's important to include that reminder.)

Comment: Thanks a lot. I can conclude that there are no official page for note.jar, Lotus note client API download because the integration really need the client and the client contain the API already.